# Specifying types of text from stdout in subprocess.Popen in Python

Tags: python, batch-file, tkinter, subprocess

First of all sorry if the title is not as descriptive as possible, it's hard to explain.

I have made a subprocess call to a batch and redirect all the content to python console with `print()`, the batch executed prints information messages, and I need to print a custom message, only if the batch message is a determined one.
But for some way, python detects that is not the same string.

I don't know if its an encoding issue (I encode the `readline` in `iso-8859-1` to avoid the encoding errors of `utf-8`).

Here's my code.

```
from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    import os


    gui = Tk()

    text = Text(gui)
    lb = ttk.Label(text="My bat")

    cmd = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\BAT1.bat'

    def runbat():
        proc = Popen(cmd,shell=False,stdout=PIPE)
        while True:
            line = proc.stdout.readline().decode('iso-8859-1').rstrip('\n')

            if line != '':
                myline = 'INFO Starting: Initialize communication activity (InitializeCommunication).'
                if line == myline:
                    print("That's the line!")
                print(line)
            else:
                break

    bt = ttk.Button(text="Run bat", command=runbat).grid(row=4, column=5)

    text.grid(row=6, column= 5)
    lb.grid(row=3, column=5)
    prog.grid(row=7,column=5)
    mainloop()
```

And this is the output:

```
C:\Python34\python.exe "C:/Users/User/Documents/Desarrollo/Boos Production Manager/preferences/multioneproof.py"

C:\Users\User\Documents\Desarrollo\Boos Production Manager\preferences>cd /D C: 

C:\Users\User\Documents\Desarrollo\Boos Production Manager\preferences>cd C:\Program Files\Philips MultiOne Workflow 

C:\Program Files\Philips MultiOne Workflow>MultiOneWorkflow.exe /f "C:/Users/User/Desktop/A.xml" /w "Z:\Spain Factory\multione configuration\verify.txt" /p S /lu true /v info /c Halt 
WARN Parameter IncludeUniqueIdOfDeviceInLabelData is provided without the GenerateAndExportLabelData parameter.
INFO Philips MultiOne Workflow version 3.11.91.28
INFO OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Home. Computer name: PC-DAVID. Application path: C:\Program Files\Philips MultiOne Workflow\MultiOneWorkflow.exe. Running as administrator: no. Format: Espa¤ol (Espa¤a) [es-ES], date format: dd/MM/yyyy, right to left: no, decimal separator: [,].
INFO Key: N/A. Profile: Debug. TwelveNc: N/A. 
INFO Privileges: 0-10V / 1-10V: All. 0-10V / 1-10V (LED Driver): All. ActiLume: All. ActiLume wired: All. ActiLume wireless: All. Active Cooling: All. Adjustable Light Output: All. Adjustable Light Output Minimum: All. Adjustable Output Current: All. Adjustable Output Current Multi-Channel: All. Adjustable Startup Time: All. AmpDim: All. Coded Light: All. Coded Light Pwm: All. Coded Light Randomize: All. Coded Mains Scene Settings: All. Coded Mains Standalone Receiver: All. ComBox: All. Constant Light Output: All. Constant Light Output LITE: All. Constant Light Output Multi-Channel: All. Correlated Color Temperature Dual Channel: All. Correlated color temperature: All. Corridor Mode: All. DALI 102 variables: All. DALI Power Supply: All. DC Emergency: All. Dali 202 variables: All. Daylight override / Daylight switching: All. Device Info: All. Diagnostics: All. Diagnostics Emergency: All. Diagnostics Motor Controller: All. Dimming Interface: All. Driver Addressing: All. Driver Temperature Limit: All. Dwell Time: All. Dynadimmer: All. Emergency: All. End Of Life indication: All. Energy Meter: All. FCC Test Mode Settings: All. Factory link: All. Field Task Tuning: All. Field Task Tuning/Occupancy Sensing/Daylight Harvesting: All. Lamp Burn-in: All. Lamp selection: All. Late Stage Configuration: All. Light Source Age: All. LineSwitch: All. Load Fault Indicator Thresholds: All. Logical Signal Input: All. Lumen Level: All. LumiStep: All. Luminaire (Fixture) Information: All. Luminaire Production Test: All. Min dim level: All. Module Temperature Protection: All. Motor Control: All. NTC on LedSet: All. OEM Write Protection: All. Occupancy / Daylight: All. Occupancy sharing / Group light behavior: All. PowerBox: All. Push Button Unit LCU2070: All. Push Button Unit LCU2071: All. Quick Lamp Start: All. Relay Switched Output: All. SR Power Supply: All. Set Lamp uptime: All. Step Dimming: All. Touch and Dim: All. 
INFO On warnings: halt
INFO Using Write&Verify.
INFO Multiple device configuring: Disabled
INFO Commission all: Disabled
INFO Check device model: Enabled
INFO DALI factory new: Disabled
INFO Starting: Prepare system activity (PrepareSystem).
INFO Success: Prepare system activity (PrepareSystem).
INFO Starting: Select feature file activity (OpenFile).
INFO Opening features file
INFO Provided file: c:/users/user/desktop/a.xml
INFO Success: Select feature file activity (OpenFile).
INFO Starting: Initialize communication activity (InitializeCommunication).
INFO Success: Initialize communication activity (InitializeCommunication).
INFO Starting: Identify device activity (IdentifyDevice).
INFO Devices identified: 0
ERROR No connected devices were found
ERROR Failure: Identify device activity (IdentifyDevice).
INFO Starting: Stop activity (Stop).
INFO Success: Stop activity (Stop).
INFO End

C:\Program Files\Philips MultiOne Workflow>echo 500  1>"Z:\Spain Factory\multione configuration\log.txt" 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So I think it must print my custom sentence when it comes to the correct line, but for some reason it doesn't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if line != '' :
    myline = 'INFO Starting: Initialize communication activity (InitializeCommunication).'
    if str(myline) in str(line) :
        print("That's the line!")
    print(line)
else :
    break
```

In this your 'line' variable value have extra trailing spaces which is not in 'myline' variable that's why your equal to if condition fails, if you use in condition it will solve this issue.

Comment: That's it.
I have posted a response before but I haven't read correctly your answer.
I don't think about the `in` statement.
Thank you.

Comment: @double-beep Thank you for your suggestion, this was my first answer so i wasn't aware about that.